# What is the purpose of this statement in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, programming

I see syntax quit similar to this very frequently:

4'd0

Sometimes it is associated with an assign statement:

assign S0 = 2'b00;

I tried searching online however I could not find any sources.

Comment: It is very hard for me to believe that the answer to this question was at all difficult to locate online.

Comment: Actually, it would be hard to search for if you didn't know what is was called. But any basic tutorial would show this.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply how a value is given. `4'd0` is a **4-bit** value, given in base 10 (*d*ecimal), with value 0. `2'b00` is a **2-bit** value, given in *b*inary, with value 0.

The following four values are equivalent and all equal to fifteen:

```
4'b1111 (binary)
4'd15 (decimal)
4'hf (hexadecimal)
4'o17 (octal)
```

Comment: That makes sooo much sense! But when do you normally use them? For example, if I wanted to assign a [4:0] bit array to the value of 1101 would I do something similar to S0 [4:0] = 4'b1101? Where each bit S[0] - S[3] would contain each binary number 1101 respectively?

Comment: @Code4life Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

These are *integer literal constants* defined in section 5.7.1 of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM. Anyone using Verilog/SystemVerilog should have a free copy available at https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=80